# ImageMagick command without intermediary file fails

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm working on the example from ImageMagick called "Gel" Effects on the [ImageMagick Example pages](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/advanced/#gel_effects).

Instead of executing the ImageMagick script in many steps with intermediary images, I want to do it in ONE step with no intermediary files.

My code looks like this (95% same as the example):

```
convert.exe -size 150x64 xc:none  -fill green 
-draw "roundrectangle 10,10 140,54 8,8"  

( +clone -alpha extract -blur 0x12 -shade 110x0 
   -normalize -sigmoidal-contrast 16,60% -evaluate multiply .5 
   -roll +4+8 +clone -compose Screen -composite ) -compose In  -composite 

( +clone -alpha extract  -blur 0x2 -shade 0x90 -normalize -blur 0x2  
    +level 60,100%  -alpha On ) -compose Multiply -composite    

-font Verdana-Bold  -pointsize 20  -fill white  -stroke black -gravity Center  
    -annotate 0 "Download" -trim -repage 0x0+7+7   

( +clone -background navy -shadow 80x4+4+4 ) +swap -background none -flatten  
ButtonTest.png"
```

These steps are copies of the steps in the example.

The problem is the last clone step:

```
( +clone -background navy -shadow 80x4+4+4 ) +swap -background none -flatten
```

cause the otherwise very nice image to become dark. I.e. no dropshadow is added. Up until that step, the one command works very nicely.

Furthermore. IF I **save** the image before the last step, like this:

```
convert.exe -size 150x64 xc:none  -fill green 
-draw "roundrectangle 10,10 140,54 8,8"  

( +clone -alpha extract -blur 0x12 -shade 110x0 
   -normalize -sigmoidal-contrast 16,60% -evaluate multiply .5 
   -roll +4+8 +clone -compose Screen -composite ) -compose In  -composite 

( +clone -alpha extract  -blur 0x2 -shade 0x90 -normalize -blur 0x2  
    +level 60,100%  -alpha On ) -compose Multiply -composite    

-font Verdana-Bold  -pointsize 20  -fill white  -stroke black -gravity Center  
    -annotate 0 "Download" -trim -repage 0x0+7+7   
tempbutton.png
```

and then perform the last clone on the tempbutton, like this:

```
convert.exe tempbutton.png
( +clone -background navy -shadow 80x4+4+4 ) +swap -background none -flatten
downloadbutton.png
```

then it works.

How can I avoid to save the image as that last step, and make this one big command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link to the Example page does not lead me to what you possibly used as your template (stating it's *"95% same as the example"*).

However, after some reformatting for better readability, for removing a typo and for adaption to my own environments (which needs the **`" (...) "`** parts escaped with back slashes like this: **`" \( ... \) "`**, I inserted an additional `-compose src-over` just before the final `-flatten` operator:

```
convert -size 150x64 xc:none -fill green -draw "roundrectangle 10,10 140,54 8,8" \
                                                                                 \
  \( +clone -alpha extract -blur 0x12 -shade 110x0                               \
     -normalize -sigmoidal-contrast 16,60% -evaluate multiply .5                 \
     -roll +4+8 +clone -compose Screen -composite                                \
  \)                                                                             \
                                                                                 \
  -compose In  -composite                                                        \
                                                                                 \
  \( +clone -alpha extract  -blur 0x2 -shade 0x90 -normalize -blur 0x2           \
     +level 60,100%  -alpha On                                                   \
  \)                                                                             \
                                                                                 \
  -compose Multiply -composite                                                   \
  -font Verdana-Bold  -pointsize 20  -fill white  -stroke black -gravity Center  \
  -annotate 0 "Download" -trim -repage 0x0+7+7                                   \
                                                                                 \
  \( +clone -background navy -shadow 80x4+4+4                                    \
  \)                                                                             \                                                                                      \
  +swap -background none -compose src-over -flatten                              \
    "ButtonTest.png"
```

The reason for that is this:

1. `-compose <some-composite-operator>` is an ***Image Setting***.
2. Its default value is `src-over`.
3. The `-flatten` operator you use just before writing the final result image is just a shortcut for a `-layers flatten` operation.
4. The `-layers flatten` operation works like this:

   > "Create a canvas the size of the first images virtual canvas using the current `-background` color, and `-compose` each image in turn onto that canvas. Images falling outside that canvas is clipped. Final image will have a zero virtual canvas offset." [see IM docu](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#layers)
5. Image Settings like `-compose ...` persist until the complete command has ended, or until they are explicitly changed by another `-compose ...` setting later on the command line.
6. Your previously supplied `-compose Multiply` setting is still active while you do the final `-flatten` (a.k.a. `-layers flatten`). That gives the output you see...

However, when you run your second, separate command to create your button, you start afresh:

1. The previous `-compose Multiply` setting is no longer known.
2. An *explicit* `-compose <something>` setting is not given for the `-flatten` operation.
3. Hence, the *implicit* default `-compose src-over` is used for `-flatten`.

So to integrate that setting into the one, single command for ImageMagick, you have to reset the previous `-compose multiply` by running `-compose src-over -flatten` before writing the output.

Here is a comparison *"before"* (your command's output, left) and *"after"* (my command's output, right) the modifications I proposed:

[image: ButtonTest.png, first attempt by OP]     
[image: ButtonTest.png, with modified command]

---

You should study my previous answer on the topic of *"The Architecture of the ImageMagick Command Line"* here:

- **[ImageMagick Command-Line Option Order (and Categories of Command-Line Parameters)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26940206/359307)**

It explains the difference in the following categories of ImageMagick command line params. To understand these differences is essential if you want to construct complex IM commands with multiple operations happening:

1. ***Image Settings***
2. ***Image Operators***
3. ***Image Sequence Operators***
4. ***Image Stack Operators***

Comment: That's an awesome answer. Thanks you very much Kurt

Comment: @Andy: feel free to browse my other answers re. my favorite topics ImageMagick, PDF, PostScript or Ghostscript -- maybe you find a few other "gems" there...  :-)