# Node.js move files via CLI to directory

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface, imagemagick-convert

I'm building a script that automates all my daily needs with one command line execution.

ImageMagick is used to compress / convert images. But after doing that task I want those images to be moved to another directory. Unfortunately I'm working on a windows machine ... my command `move C:\Automatik\src\IMG\*.jpg C:\Automatik\dist\IMG\` didn't work via Node.js Command Prompt. It only works in CMD!

I need either a npm package or another command for doing this.

Maybe someone knows how to move files with `ImageMagick`? The `-path`-argument didn't work for me...

`mogrify -format jpg -quality 85 src/IMG/*.*`

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: Might want to go have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579055/how-i-move-files-on-node-js)

Comment: @thezadmin thx for your reply. All I need is a shorthand command for my scripts-section in package.json. I don't want to write additional code (if that's possible ...). If I got it right I do have to write full code in JS to use `fs` or is there a CLI?

Comment: As far as I know, since fs is a module within node it can only be called within node itself.

Comment: Thx @thezadmin I came up with the `ImageMagick` solution!

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304480/batch-resize-images-and-output-images-to-new-folder-with-imagemagick#answer-18018161) which suggests the `-path` argument should work. I think the pertinent part to your issue is that the output directories you point to must exist (as per this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304480/batch-resize-images-and-output-images-to-new-folder-with-imagemagick#comment-57755244)).

Comment: @RobC thx for the hint! My mistake was in `ImageMagick` with setting the `-path` at the end ... It threw a `unrecognized method` error. You have to declare the path before setting the image(s) source(s).

Answer (score 1):

For Windows it's a bit more tricky then on Unix-systems. But here's the solution with ImageMagick:

`FOR %a in (src/IMG/*.png) DO mogrify -strip -path dist/IMG/ -format jpg -quality 85 src/IMG/%a`

We do have to care about the syntax as -path at the end throws an error!